# Como limpar textbox de outro Window? - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Segue código:

```
MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();

mainwindow.listbox1.Items.Clear();
// tentativa
//mainwindow.listbox1.ItemsSource = null;
```

Eu tento limpar `listbox` de outro form... acontece nada.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: cara... acho que nao seria duplicada.. as outras perguntas não sao com WPF ? ou estou enganado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está criando uma nova instância da Window, consequentemente o controle será novo e etc!

Para acessar controles em outras janelas com WPF, você precisa declarar o controle como público primeiro, por exemplo:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

Depois você consegue fazer uma busca de todas as janelas na sua aplicação fazendo dessa forma:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
    {
       (window as MainWindow).textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```