# Como atualizar textbox de outra janela WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Galera tenho 2 janelas wpf (C#)

A cadastrarconta
B buscarfornecedor

Dentro da janela A a um textbox e um botao que abre a janela B, 
Dentro da janela B tem um textbox e um button.

Como eu faço para passar para a janela A (que esta aberta), o conteudo do textbox da Janela B (Que também esta aberta) sem ter que reabrir a janela A.

Minha class da janela B

```
   //IGNORE - Aqui consigo pegar o conteudo vinda da janela A
    public BFuncio_Clientes_Fornec(ContasaPagarCadastrar contasaPagarCadastrar)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
       //IGNORE Aqui consigo pegar a informação da janela A e colocar na B
        termobusca.Text = contasaPagarCadastrar.pagante.Text;

    }
    //AQUI É O EVENTO AO MUDAR DE FOCO NO BOTAO DA JANELA B
    private void Seleciona_LostFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //AQUI SERIA UTILIZADO PARA SETAR O CONTEUDO NA CLASS DA JANELA A
        ContasaPagarCadastrar novopagante = new ContasaPagarCadastrar();
        novopagante.pagante.Text = termobusca.Text;
        //AQUI SERIA PARA ABRIR UMA NOVA JANELA A
       //MAIS EU NAO QUERO ABRIR, QUERO SÓ ATUALIZAR O TEXTBOX DA JANELA JÁ ABERTA A
        novopagante.Show();
    }
```

Comment: na verdade é duplicada de outra pergunta relacionada a WPF e não Windows Forms..
No caso essa
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262808/como-limpar-textbox-de-outro-window-wpf/262826#262826

Comment: eu não tinha votado para fechar como duplicata... mas no caso, é duplicata dessa outra questão que o @ThiagoLoureiro levantou, não da que está atualmente