# Comunicação entre ViewModel's: retornar dados para tela anterior

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Tenho uma tela `A` que tem um campo texto e um button, esse button da tela `A`, abre uma segunda tela `B`.

Essa tela `B` tem um outro campo texto para preencher e salvar, quando a pessoa clicar em salvar a tela fecha, e o que ela preencheu na tela `B` tem que aparecer preenchido no campo da tela `A`.

Usei tela `A` e `B` como exemplo, como fazer usando *MVVM* ?

Encontrei essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263431/como-atualizar-textbox-de-outra-janela-wpf), mas o que quero fazer é o inverso com *MVVM*.

Comment: Está a usar algum WPF framework? Qual?

Comment: @ramaral estou usando [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) mas se fizer um exemplo sem prism também aceito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é usar o [Event Aggregator Pattern](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx).

Escreva uma classe para o evento:

```
public class TelaBResultEvent : PubSubEvent<string>{}
```

No contrutor da ViewModel da tela A subscreva o evento:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<TelaBResultEvent>().Subscribe(OnTelaBResult);
```

- `eventAggregator` é um `IEventAggregator` injectado no construtor.
- `OnTelaBResult` é um método do ViewModel com a assinatura

  ```
  public void OnTelaBResult(string telaBResult)
  ```

  que será chamado quando o evento for recebido.
  Use o valor recebido no parâmetro `telaBResult` no campo de texto.

No ViewModel da tela B publique o evento quando salvar/fechar a tela, passado o valor do campo de texto.

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<TelaBResultEvent>().Publish("Texto a publicar");
```

- `_eventAggregator` é um campo/propriedade ao qual foi atribuído um `IEventAggregator` injectado no construtor do ViewModel.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado, outra pergunta, alem dessa forma conhece outra? ou será que não existe? sabe me dizer.

Comment: Porventura existirão outras. No entanto esta é a forma preconizada  pelo Prism(e outros frameworks WPF) para a comunicação entre ViewModel's.